# How to print the first ten rows of a JSON file in R

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have an R dataframe and converted it to json format using the jsonlite package

```
jsonData <- toJSON(dataset)
```

I want to validate if the conversion was successful, the dataset is very large. How do I print the first 5 rows in the json file?

Comment: `jsonData[1:5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Converting R objects to JSON

There are several packages that implement a `toJSON()` function, for example, `jsonlite`, `rjson`, and `RJSONIO`. I will use `jsonlite` in the following. The solution also works with `RJSONIO`, but not with `rjson`.

I have not found a direct way to print just a subset of lines from a JSON string. The reason is that all three packages return a single character (i.e., a character vector of length one) and not a character vector, where each row of the JSON string occupies a single element:

```
length(jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars))
```

Indeed, the converted object is one long line of text:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars)
## [{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.62,"qsec":16.46,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4"},{"mpg":21,"cyl":6,"disp":160,"hp":110,"drat":3.9,"wt":2.875,"qsec":17.02,"vs":0,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":4,"_row":"Mazda RX4 Wag"},{"mpg":22.8,"cyl":4,"disp":108,"hp":93,"drat":3.85,"wt":2.32,"qsec":18.61,"vs":1,"am":1,"gear":4,"carb":1,"_row":"Datsun 710"},{"mpg":21.4,"cyl":6,"disp":258,"hp":110,"drat":3.08,"wt":3.215,"qsec":19.44,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":1,"_row":"Hornet 4 Drive"},{"mpg":18.7,"cyl":8,"disp":360,"hp":175,"drat":3.15,"wt":3.44,"qsec":17.02,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":2,"_row":"Hornet Sportabout"},{"mpg":18.1,"cyl":6,"disp":225,"hp":105,"drat":2.76,"wt":3.46,"qsec":20.22,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":1,"_row":"Valiant"},{"mpg":14.3,"cyl":8,"disp":360,"hp":245,"drat":3.21,"wt":3.57,"qsec":15.84,"vs":0,"am":0,"gear":3,"carb":4,"_row":"Duster 360"},{"mpg":24.4,"cyl":4,"disp":146.7,"hp":62,"drat":3.69,"wt":3.19,"qsec":20,"vs":1,"am":0,"gear":4,"c... <truncated>
```

Since there is only one line, you obviously gain nothing by printing just the first few lines.

But the function `toJSON` from `jsonlite` (and the one from `RJSONIO`) allows you to break up the JSON string into lines (I truncated the output by hand, because it is too long):

```
jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars, pretty = TRUE)
## [
##   {
##     "mpg": 21,
##     "cyl": 6,
##     "disp": 160,
##     "hp": 110,
##     "drat": 3.9,
##     "wt": 2.62,
## ...
```

It is still a character vector of length one, but the lines are now separated by line breaks (`\n`), which can be used to reach your goal:

```
length(jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars, pretty = TRUE))
## [1] 1
as.character(jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars, pretty = TRUE))
## [1] "[\n  {\n    \"mpg\": 21,\n    \"cyl\": 6,\n    \"disp\": 160,\n    \"hp\": 110,\n    \"drat\": 3.9,\n    \"wt\": 2.62,\n    \"qsec\": 16.46,\n    \"vs\": 0,\n    \"am\": 1,\n    \"gear\": 4,\n    \"carb\": 4,\n    \"_row\": \"Mazda RX4\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"mpg\": 21,\n    \"cyl\": 6,\n    \"disp\": 160,\n    \"hp\": 110,\n    \"drat\": 3.9,\n    \"wt\": 2.875,\n    \"qsec\": 17.02,\n    \"vs\": 0,\n    \"am\": 1,\n    \"gear\": 4,\n    \"carb\": 4,\n    \"_row\": \"Mazda RX4 Wag\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"mpg\": 22.8,\n    \"cyl\": 4,\n    \"disp\": 108,\n    \"hp\": 93,\n    \"drat\": 3.85,\n    \"wt\": 2.32,\n    \"qsec\": 18.61,\n    \"vs\": 1,\n    \"am\": 1,\n    \"gear\": 4,\n    \"carb\": 1,\n    \"_row\": \"Datsun 710\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"mpg\": 21.4,\n    \"cyl\": 6,\n    \"disp\": 258,\n    \"hp\": 110,\n    \"drat\": 3.08,\n    \"wt\": 3.215,\n    \"qsec\": 19.44,\n    \"vs\": 1,\n    \"am\": 0,\n    \"gear\": 3,\n    \"carb\": 1,\n    \"_row\": \"Hornet 4 Drive\"\n  },\n  {\n  ... <truncated>
```

#### Printing only a subset of lines from a JSON

I wrote a little function that takes a JSON object as input and prints a subset of its lines. It only works, if you use `pretty = TRUE` when creating the JSON object. Here it is:

```
print_json_lines <- function(json, lines) {

  # break up into lines
  json_lines <- strsplit(json, "\n")[[1]]

  # get desired lines
  json_lines <- json_lines[lines]

  # print
  cat(paste(json_lines, collapse = "\n"))

  # return invisily
  invisible(json_lines)

}
```

It uses `strsplit()` to split the line into a vector of characters, with one entry per line. Then it is possible to pick lines by normal indexing with `[]`. Since simply printing a character vector will likely print several character strings on one line, I combine the subset of lines again into a single string (with `paste()`) and separate the lines with `\n`. This leads to a nicely formatted output:

```
print_json_lines(jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars, pretty = TRUE), 1:5)
## [
##   {
##     "mpg": 21,
##     "cyl": 6,
##     "disp": 160,
```

#### Remark about the different JSON packages

As I mentioned in the beginning, this solution works for both, `jsonlite` and `RJSONIO`. The reason is simply that they both allow you to break up the JSON string into lines with `pretty = TRUE`. However, the output looks different when you use `RJSONIO`, because it uses different conventions in the conversion:

```
print_json_lines(RJSONIO::toJSON(mtcars, pretty = TRUE), 1:5)
## {
##     "mpg" : [
##             21,
##             21,
##             22.8,
```

The function does not work with `rjson`, because there is no way that I am aware of to have the JSON object split into lines.